Exoplayer HLS Cache
Is it possible to cache played hls stream from exoplayer? I was reading a lot about caching of other media types, but I couldn't find any solution for hls streams. There are some old comments like the different and adaptive bitrate problem. I am using the hls.js for my web player and it handles perfectly the cache for the same streams. My main problem are the streams which are available for only few seconds on the servers, I would like to be able to rewind back more than 4-5 seconds. Thank you in advance.
PS: I am using the latest media3 version of exoplayer and I've tried to use the CacheDataSource and some other solutions that I found online, but nothing worked.
